# How to use non-english language in code

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

I'm italian and I've to develop a multilingual drupal site but english translations of strings (that should be added in code or templates) will be done in the future.

Is there a way to use in code a non-english language and use t() and other functions to translate them in english?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK core's does not support (and could take a while to do so) keyed based translation (like Symfony or other do). Theres [an idea](https://www.drupal.org/project/ideas/issues/630432) queued but seems to fall on deaf ears.